# Twitter API: Getting the number of tweets for a specific time and location?

Tags: r, api, twitter, count, location

For example, getting the information that there were 56000 tweets in Los Angeles, CA on May 30th, 2015 at 5:00 PM. Ideally, I would like to access tweets as far back in time as possible. The main issue with this seems to be getting tweets from the past - Twitter's REST API only has tweets for about the past 7 days.

The only way that I am thinking of is manually counting the tweets for a particular location and time from Twitter's website directly, but surely there must be a better way.

Is there some simple way to accomplish this that I'm not thinking of, or any libraries or frameworks that optimize this task?

As of now, I'm trying to use R, but I'm not sure if other languages or frameworks would be better suited for this.

Comment: What have you done so far in term of code ? You should perhaps build a query first with [twitteR](https://www.google.cz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiAvryF7ZnUAhVnKcAKHUvSDs4QFggjMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcran.r-project.org%2Fweb%2Fpackages%2FtwitteR%2FtwitteR.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFUt31RileWvPKmJ_iXsHxqvvoAQQ&sig2=jiryrgNos_xyZHtycOo02A&cad=rja) and look at the documentation on [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/) . There are some limitations on the number of request you can do on Twitter's server also that depend on the complexity of them.

Comment: Check out [Gnip](https://gnip.com),Twitter’s enterprise API platform.

Comment: @PierreChevallier - twitteR has been deprecated in favour of [`rtweet`](https://github.com/mkearney/rtweet)

Comment: Oh ok my bad, thanks a lot I'll have a look at this package

Comment: @PierreChevallier In terms of code, I've built a query that can get tweets from a specified location using `rtweet`, but I'm not sure how to get tweets from a specific date or time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will never achieve your goal, even if you pay for Gnip. The reason is less than one to two percent of twitter accounts reveal their location.

If that is not a problem for you, and you don't want to pay for Gnip, you can use [statuses/filter](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/reference/post/statuses/filter), which is a streaming endpoint, along with the `locations` parameter. Then you would simply count the tweets as they come. However, you would not have access to historical information.

Gnip would also give you the historical tweets you desire, and Gnip has some intelligent algorithms that will increase the number of geo-locatable tweets to around 20%, more or less.